# $.each animation running separately

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

I'm trying to run each animation function one after the other instead of all at once.

This is what I've got so far:

```
   $(document).ready(function(){ 
        var bars = $('.bar');
        bars.each(function(){
            var widthpercent = $(this).attr("data-percent");
            $(this).fadeIn();
            $(this).animate({width:widthpercent},500);
        });
    });
```

I've tried using `.delay()` and `setTimeout()` in various combinations to no avail.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? Thank you!

Comment: Tip: Don't use `$(this).attr('data-percent')`, use `$(this).data('percent')`. jQuery gives you a nice helper.

Comment: Thank you for the tip I will bare that in mind!

Comment: @meagar: There are downsides to that. It's slower, it parses the data as JSON, which isn't always desired, and it stores the data in `jQuery.cache`, which is often unnecessary.

Comment: You want each bar to load one after the other or the fade/animate?

Comment: I want them to load in and animate one at a time, at the moment. All load and animate in sync

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like you're looking for `animate`'s `complete` function. You can write a recursive function to keep calling the function in the `complete` function until all the items have been animated. To simplify: every time one element is animated, a callback is fired that animates the next element. That is the purpose of the `complete` parameter, so I'm certain that is what you're looking for.

Here's an example you can adapt to your specific needs.

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/EvusIya/7/edit)

```
var $divs = $('div');

function animate(element) {
  $(element).animate({height: '30px'}, {
    complete: function() {
      if (current < $divs.length-1) {
        ++current;
        animate($divs[current]);
      }
    }
  });
}

var current = 0;
animate($divs[current]);
```

Further, this same logic can be applied to your `fadeIn`. Just wrap fadeIn's callback around that logic, like this:

[Live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/EvusIya/8/edit)

```
var $divs = $('div');

function animate(element) {
  $(element).fadeIn(function() { //now the animation is a callback to the fadeIn
    $(element).animate({height: '70px'}, {
      complete: function() {
        if (current < $divs.length-1) {
          ++current;
          animate($divs[current]);
        }
      }
    });
  });
}

var current = 0;
animate($divs[current]);
```

And here's your code: [live demo here (click).](http://jsbin.com/EvusIya/6/edit)

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 

var $divs = $('.bar');

function animate(element) {
  $(element).fadeIn(function() { //you could unwrap this depending on what you're looking for
    var widthpercent = $(element).attr("data-percent");
    $(element).animate({
      width:widthpercent,
      duration: '500ms'
    }, {
      complete: function() {
        if (current < $divs.length-1) {
          ++current;
          animate($divs[current]);
        }
      }
    });
  }); //end fadeIn callback
}

var current = 0;
animate($divs[current]);

});
```

Comment: this is the best solution, no timeouts needed

Comment: This answer is (should be) the correct solution. It is more clear to your intents and it doesn't rely on hoping the timeouts sync up with the animations. Let the animations tell you when they are done via a callback and call it a day!

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var animate = function (el) {
    return function () {
        var widthpercent = el.data('percent');
        el.fadeIn();
        el.animate({
            width: widthpercent
        }, 500);
    }
}
var bars = $('.bar');
bars.each(function (index) {
    var $this = $(this);
    setTimeout(animate($this), index * 500);
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fb9m4/1/)

Comment: I personally wouldn't want to rely on the multiple `setTimeout` calls being perfectly in sync with the animations. Probably depends on how many there are though.

Comment: @PSL: There already is a closure. The function passed to `.each()` creates a new variable scope with each invocation, and the function passed to `setTimeout` creates a closure of that scope.

Comment: @BlueSkies oh yeah right..... But best way to do this would be to invoke a function on completion of animation for each element.

Comment: ...but if you did take that approach, you don't need to maintain the `time` variable. You can just use the counter given by `.each()`, and do `i * 500`.

Comment: @PSL: I agree. I think that's a little safer than scheduling multiple timeouts, and hoping they stay in sync.

Comment: @PSL, was this new version what you meant?

Comment: Hit the nail on the head

Comment: @user2979139 I don't mean to be selfish here...but how is this the accepted answer? the `complete` parameter of `animate` IS the answer. That's why it exists.

Comment: I tend to agree with m59 here. The setTimeout is hacky at best. Why not let the animation tell you when it is complete instead of guessing?

Comment: @m95 I couldn't get it working, and this works. That is why I have accepted the answer. Is there something i've missed

Comment: @user2979139 my answer explains it, uses it, and even has your code - all in good detail with live demos.

Comment: @m59 yes i've noticed your edit and too made changes as you'll find your answer has been marked as solution. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    var bars = $('.bar');
    bars.each(function(i){
        var widthpercent = $(this).attr("data-percent");
        $(this).delay(i*800).animate({width:widthpercent,opacity:1,},500);
    });
});
```

This will animate after delaying `800 * i` milliseconds.

See this [JSFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/superscript18/WdEMx/1/).