# css/jquery/velocity.js wipe effect

Tags: jquery, css, velocity.js

I want to mimic powerpoint's wipe effect with **css / jquery / velocity.js**.

Desired effect: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VSBB0wfccws

---

I tried to use css3 masking (svg/gradient) but with no success.

Here is a simple wipe effect with no masking:

http://plnkr.co/edit/Sys20pLwGb1MK8gBiX5a?p=preview

```
$(function(){
  $('.second').velocity({    
    width: ['100%', 0]
  },{
    duration: 2000,
    loop: true
  })
})
```

---

Preferably it should work on all modern browsers.

Comment: Take a look at [TransM.js](http://www.netzgesta.de/transm/), especially the `curl_horizontal` effect

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you want. The video does not really show it well.
[Try This Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/kFCFl4k2Aaf6tFD6AlSa?p=preview)

// Code goes here

```
$(function(){
    $('.second').velocity({    
        width: [0,'100%']
    },{
        duration: 1000,
        delay:2000,
        loop: 1
    });
    $('.first').velocity({    
        opacity:[1,0],
    },{
        duration: 600,
        delay:2000,
        loop:1
    })
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Non velocity.js tips

**css3 - with -webkit-/-moz-/-o-**

Works on chrome only (I think), you need to rewrite it (for that you can find a few help here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_transitions.asp and on the Internet :) ), but the second example is do the same what you need (works with onhover in chrome)
http://css-tricks.com/webkit-image-wipes/

If I know very well, the mask attribute only works in safari and chrome and maybe in opera too.

**jQuery**

Something like you need: http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/wipe.html

Maybe you search for this: [Nivo slider effectslicedownright](http://www.oik-plugins.com/wordpress-plugins-from-oik-plugins/wordpress-plugins/oik-nivo-slider/nivo-settings/nivo-slider-transition-effects/nivo-slider-effectslicedownright/)

**Other which can useful:**

[Jquery image transition left to right and fade in, in a slideshow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21685067/jquery-image-transition-left-to-right-and-fade-in-in-a-slideshow)

[CSS fade left to right](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12686738/css-fade-left-to-right)

[Fade effect left to right on a image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14193028/fade-effect-left-to-right-on-a-image)

[CSS Fade Between Background Images on Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6948758/css-fade-between-background-images-on-hover)

In my opinion, if there are one which works, use that, don't write another one. Mostly you can find a lot of result for this, if you search for this: jQuery fade left to right | jQuery fade left to right between two images

velocity.js tips

Maybe the answere were be here: http://julian.com/research/velocity/ at the fade & slide section

Or here: http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2014/06/18/faster-ui-animations-with-velocity-js/ the stagger section looks like that.

Answer (score 1):

Check the below link this might help you

Here is the base code

```
$('#wipe1').cycle({ 
  fx:     'wipe', 
  speed:   1000, 
  timeout: 6000, 
  delay:  -4000, 
  clip:   'l2r' 
});
```

[jquery Plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/)

Regards
Mahadevan